# Second derivative of function on a curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm stuck on a really simple problem. Consider a curve $\mathbf{r}(t)$ for $t \in [0, 1]$ and a function defined on on that curve $f(\mathbf{r}(t))$. I'm interested in $f''(\mathbf{r}(t))$. Someone wrote me a note that has it equal to
$$\mathbf{r}'(t)^T H_{f(\mathbf{r})}\mathbf{r}'(t)$$
and I can't for the life of me see why. I seem to derive
$$\mathbf{r}'(t)^T H_{f(\mathbf{r})}\mathbf{r}'(t) + \nabla_{\mathbf{r}} f \cdot \mathbf{r}''(t)$$
Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't think your answer is wrong. Maybe for the given example $\nabla_r f \cdot r''(t) =0$ ?

Comment: That must be it, I'll double check the context...